# MongoDb - Run adminCommand using .NET driver (2.4.4)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In my application I need to ensure that `featureCompatibilityVersion` is no lower than the required value as part of the integration tests environment setup.

For that I would need to execute [getParameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getParameter/) and [setFeatureCompatibilityVersion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) admin commands.

Is there a way to do it using the .NET driver ?
Was not able to find a way run using the [MongoDB.Driver 2.4.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.4.4)

The only approach I stumbled across was using the `Server.RunAdminCommand` method, which appears to be obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`runCommand`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoDatabase_RunCommand__1.htm) to get parameter.

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("admin");
BsonDocument parameter = database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 }"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var command = new BsonDocument { { "getParameter", 1 }, { "featureCompatibilityVersion", 1 } };

var mongoClient = new MongoClient();
var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("admin");

var result = mongoDatabase.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);

Console.WriteLine(result.ToJson());

// { "featureCompatibilityVersion" : { "version" : "3.6" }, "ok" : 1.0 }
```